# Stacks and Queue: inserting a value at the same time

Tags: java

I am practicing stacks and queue and I wanted to push and enqueue at the same time. is it possible to do that?

This is the 2nd class Finals.class source code

```
public class Finals {
public int [] arr;
public int top;
public int back;
public int front;
public int counter;

public Finals () {}

public Finals (int size)
{
    arr = new int[size];
    top = -1; //default for stacks
    front = -1;
    back = -1;
}


public void push (int value)
{
    top = top+1;
    back = top - 1;
    arr[top]=value;
}

public void enqueue (int value)
{
    
    back = back+1;
    arr[top]= top;
    arr[back]=value;
            
}
```

And this is the running class 1st class FinalTests Class

```
public class FinalsTest extends Finals {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Finals f = new Finals(5);
    f.push(1);
    f.push(2);
    f.enqueue(3);
```

Comment: i was trying to get an out put as [2, 1 , 3]

Comment: It is not clear what you try to achieve. Your question is unclear. If you need a data structure that is a stack and a queue together, just implement a stack, implement a queue. And then move everything together in one class. That should be straightforward.